# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SpeechRecognition' despite module being successfully installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, speech-recognition

Forgive me if this is a redundant question. I viewed a couple of similar posts and I do believe my issue is unique. I am making a simple AI Assistant using a tutorial on geeksforgeeks. Link below:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/build-a-virtual-assistant-using-python/

I wanted to tweak this to be more specific to my needs, and I think I have it all figured out, including replacing `import speech_recognition as sr` with it's python3 counterpart, `import SpeechRecognition as sr`. I am using PyCharm Community as my IDE, and for those that know it, it allows you to install missing modules used by `import` by mousing over them and clicking the prompt to install the module. Long story short, this doesn't work for SpeechRecognition. It's showing `No module named 'SpeechRecognition'` despite clicking the prompt several times and seeing that it successfully installed.

I went to the Python Terminal and tried to do this manually with the following:

```
>> pip3 install SpeechRecognition

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\[user]\PycharmProjects\[my project]\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

>> C:\Users\[user]\PycharmProjects\[my project]\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Requirement already satisfied: pip in C:\Users\[user]\PycharmProjects\[my project]\venv\lib\site-packages (21.1.2)
Collecting pip`
Using cached pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Attempting uninstall: pip`
Found existing installation: pip 21.1.2
Uninstalling pip-21.1.2:
Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1.2
Successfully installed pip-21.3.

>> pip3 install SpeechRecognition

Requirement already satisfied: pip in C:\Users\[user]\PycharmProjects\[my project]\venv\lib\site-packages (3.8.1)
```

I'm fairly new to Python and coding in general, but from I can tell it *is* installed. However, when I run the program, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user]\PycharmProjects\[my project]\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import SpeechRecognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SpeechRecognition'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, and cheers.

Comment: So you're going to File->Settings->Project:[project name]->Python Interpreter, and clicking the plus button, then searching for "SpeechRecognition", then selecting it, then clicking Install? What do you have set as the Python Interpreter?

Comment: Yes, and when I double checked the SpeechRecognition package is at the top of the list here,  installed version 3.8.1, latest version 3.8.1. Python interpreter is the default one (Python 3.9) that PyCharm allows us to use with new projects

Comment: And the interpreter specifically says your project name after, right? If you click the gear icon next to the project interpreter, then select the Python 3.9 one, and click the pencil, is its path `C:\Users\[user]\PycharmProjects\[my project]\venv\Scripts\python.exe`? Is the "Associate this virtual environment with the current project" option checked? Do other packages that you install work, or is that the only one with the issue?

Comment: Correct. All other packages work. Only SpeechRecognition has an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I have it all figured out, including replacing `import speech_recognition as sr` with it's python3 counterpart, `import SpeechRecognition as sr`

This is your issue. I can't find anywhere that says you should import the library that way. All the [official examples](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/examples), and the [official readme](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#readme), state that it should be imported via:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

Again I'm not sure why you thought it should be imported differently just because you're using Python 3. I will say that GeeksForGeeks is generally *not* recognized as a good source of information by this site's community. I highly recommend using other sites, and also always starting from official sources.

Comment: Marked as answer. This fixed my issue. At first speech_recognition had the same issue but after double checking the install it worked just fine.